# Shared Facebook Button in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, facebook, button, shared

I am trying to put a Shared Button Facebook in a blog making with AngularJS.
    The code is App.js:

```
app.controller('SinglePostController', ['$scope','$http','$routeParams', function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
    $http.get('json/jobs.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.post = data[$routeParams.id];
    });

    $scope.share = function(post){
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Higher Recruitment',
        link: 'http://higherrecruiting.com/jobs/post/'+post.id,
        picture: post.img,
        caption: 'Higher Recruitment',
        description: 'Higher Recruitment',
        message: 'Higher Recruitment'
    });
  }
  }]);
```

Header:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '740701336108341',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And singlepost.php

```
  <small>Share with your friends:</small>
  <button ng-click="share(post)""> <img src="web/img/logo-facebook.png" style="width:40px;" /></button>
  <br><br>
```

The problem is that Facebook only show the principal website, with the logo and only a link, but the code that show take the image and link

You can see in:

http://higherrecruiting.com/jobs#/post/4

Comment: Facebook is in the process of removing all ways to set these values at runtime, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations You need to define title, description and thumbnail via OG meta tags.

Comment: I see. I had only one header, I had to do differents headers. Now it work correctly.